# Double and Trible asterisk in C++

Tags: c++

I want more clarification about the reason for using double and triple asterisks as the following part of the code?

```
double ***pop, ***pop_old; // LBM populations (old and new)
double **density; // fluid density
double **velocity_x; // fluid velocity (x-component)
double **velocity_y; // fluid velocity (y-component)
double **force_x; // fluid force (x-component)
double **force_y; // fluid force (y-component)
```

Comment: In c++ you wouldn't use these at all usually. C++ provides container classes like e.g. `std::vector<double>`, you can use instead of manually managed memory and dealing with raw pointers to those addresses obtained.

Comment: [Three star programmer](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer).